# BeaconParser instance issue Android beacon library

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am trying to collect temperature and humidity from beacons, that sends this raw data:

```
020106 020AFC 0A16 ABFE 70BF01 00DB00DB
```

where:

```
0x02 – length (2 bytes)
0x01 – type (flags)
0x06 – value (BIN=00000110)

0x02 -length (2 bytes)
0x0A type («Tx Power Level»)
0xFC – value (DEC =-4)

0x0A – length (10 bytes)
0x16 - type («Service Data - 16-bit UUID»
0xABFE - UUID = FEAB
0x70 – frame type (temperature and humidity)
0xBF – TX@1m
0x01 – TX power

0x00DB – temperature (DEC=219 = 21.9 C)
0x00DB – humidity (DEC – 219= 21.9C)
```

I am trying to build an instance, but it looks like that it is not correct, WAIDW?

```
m:9-10=feab, i:11-14, p:6-6, d:14-17
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`"s:0-1=feab,m:2-2=70,i:3-8,p:3-3,d:5-6,d:7-8"`

That expression will:

- match on a 16 bit service UUID 0xFEAB (which you show)
- make sure the first byte after the service UUID is 0x70 (which you show).  This will ensure it is a temp and humidity frame
- put the full bytes of the frame into the first identifier field accessible by `beacon.getId1()` (this is not very useful, but you are required to have at least one identifier field for your beacon parser)
- put the raw temperature value into the first data field accessible by `beacon.beacon.getDataFields().get(0)`
- put the raw humidity value into the second data field accessible by `beacon.beacon.getDataFields().get(1)`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for a reply. I tried your instance, but `addRangeNotifier` method is returning an empty list. Here are some logs: 
`got record
Processing pdu type 16: 020106020afc0a16abfe70bf0100e700a8ZEROS with startIndex: 8, endIndex: 16
Ignoring pdu type 01
This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 70 seen
Bytes are: 020106020afc0a16abfe70bf0100e700a800...
Processing pdu type FF: 0201060aff5d05000202010b06000d094c48422d3839303034443444ZEROS with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
Beacon packet detected for: id1: 0xbf0100e700a8 with rssi -59
beacon detected : id1: 0xbf0100e700a8
`

Comment: This indicates it *is* detecting the beacon `Beacon packet detected for: id1: 0xbf0100e700a8 with rssi -59 beacon detected : id1: 0xbf0100e700a8`.  If your beacon list is empty in `didRangeBeaconsInRegion`, make sure your region definition you use in `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` matches the identifier of your beacon.  Since the identifier is pretty much unpredictable, this means you really must use an wildcard Region definition like `new Region("wildcard", null, null, null)`.  If you still have trouble, please show how you set up ranging.